# jQuery UI Dialog buttons not visible

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Having the following code:

```
$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog({
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title: "Title",
        height: 650,
        width: 600,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Send",
            click: function() {
                // ...
            }
        }]
});
```

The button is not visible in the dialog. Any tips or hints, do I miss something?

PS: I tried this example from @palmplam too, not working either:

```
$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    title: "Title",
    height: 650,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {"Send" : function() {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add buttons like this :

```
buttons : {text:function},{secondtext:secondfunction},...
```

With your code, it's like this :

```
$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    title: "Title",
    height: 650,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {"Send" : function() {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Or perhaps you could add buttons after the dialog was init like this :

```
$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog('option', 
                                       'buttons', 
                                       {"Send" : function() {
                                           // ...
                                       }});
```

Comment: This is not working, I tried this syntax before, without success. I can't see where my error is and why this does not work as expected...

Comment: Did you init your dialog after the document was ready ? with `$(function() { // your init dialog code here }` ?

Comment: I'm calling/opening the dialog "on the fly", when the user clicks a special button within the application.

Comment: Did you use debug tools like `fireBug` on firefox or an other ? any alert in the console ? You're code seems ok...

Comment: Yep, I'm using the Chrome Debugger. No errors, the dialog itself is displayes without any problems - beside the invisible buttons.

Comment: Ok, so try to add buttons on the fly too, like this `$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog('option', 'buttons', {...});`, i add this code in my answer.

Comment: Does not work either...I helped myself with creating a <button> and registering a click() event for it, though I want to know why there are still no buttons...anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: Should that not be an array?
buttons : [{text:function},{secondtext:secondfunction},...]

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this 'jquery-1.8.2.min.js'. Just add this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's been few months and you've probably moved on by now, but FWIW:

I am no expert on jQuery UI internals, but I have been struggling with buttons not displaying for longer than I care to admit, a problem that arose after I upgraded from 1.8.23 to 1.10.0 (then rolled back to 1.9.2, but the problem persisted). I believe I now have a clue.

You should initialize your dialog once and only once. If you want to re-use, then you should either (1) initialize with autoOpen set to false; when you want to (re-)open, reset options if needed and call "open"; or (2) call "destroy" on your dialog so you can reinitialize it if/when you need it again, without getting into trouble.

So, it looks like I was doing it "wrong" all along, but getting away with it until version > 1.8.23.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the above appears to be true, but for the sake of full disclosure, I should confess that I also found a `$('div.ui-dialog-buttonpane').hide()` somewhere in my rat's nest of code, which was -- duh -- hiding my buttonpanes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#feedback_dialog_container').dialog({    
    height:auto,                                
    width:auto,
    modal:true,
    buttons:{"Send":send}//function call send
});
function send()  {
    //function code here
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add some explanation as to why your block of code solves the OP's issue. Thanks!